# python division is not accurate

Tags: python-3.x, division

So i have a problem where i'm trying to do a division of 20-digit number.

my code:

```
result = 61519713751187780547/3
print(result)
print(int(result))
```

output:

```
2.0506571250395927e+19
20506571250395926528
```

expected output of 61519713751187780547/3 is:

```
20506571250395926849 
#calculated using full precision calculator at https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html
```

Im very confused on what's wrong or did i do anything wrong. The difference between the output and the expected output is as much as 300+.
The number is divisible by 3 so it should gives an integer result. But somehow, python gives a float result.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, `/` is float division and `//` is integer division

```
61519713751187780547//3
Out[3]: 20506571250395926849
```